# Using NPM package which requires prepublish/build from Git

Tags: npm

Currently [NPM does not run prepublish](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055) after installing a package from a Git repository.
When working with a team (i.e: I cannot ask team members to run `npm install` specifically on a dependent package), how can I use a package that requires a build step when installing from a Git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-git-install

It requires nodegit, so you'll have to be able to install that as well on your system.